# import python module with one file inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I packaged one file:

```
proxy_master
├── __init__.py
└── proxy_master.py
```

After installing it, i need to type:

```
from proxy_master import proxy_master
```

I want to know is it even possible just type?

```
import proxy_master
```

Thanks! Advices to change something may be good too, i did all like mentioned here https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: As long as the directory containing `proxy_master/` is on your Python path, both imports would be valid. Granter, they do different things

Comment: On seconds read, if you asking how to make `proxy_master.py` available as a top-level module instead of inside of a package, just don't put it inside of an (import) package.

Comment: You can put all the code of `proxy_master/proxy_master.py` into `proxy_master/__init__.py` and you are done.